# using if-else statements in React JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to display react component based on what the pair name is, but I am not sure how to get that to happen. This is the code I have so far, any suggestions?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    bases: ['EUR', 'AUD', 'CAD', 'JPY', 'NZD'],
    selectedBase: 'USD',
  };

  displayGraph = () => {
    if(document.getElementById('pairName').innerText === 'USD/EUR'){
      <Graph defaultBase={"EUR"} />
    } else if (document.getElementById('pairName').innerText === 'USD/CAD'){
      <Graph defaultBase={"CAD"} />  
    } else if(document.getElementById('pairName').innerText === 'USD/AUD'){
      <Graph defaultBase={"NZD"}/>
    } else if(document.getElementById('pairName').innerText === 'USD/NZD'){
      <Graph defaultBase={"AUD"}/>
    } else if (document.getElementById('pairName').innerText === 'USD/JPY') {
      <Graph defaultBase={"JPY"}/>
    }
  }

  render(){
    return (
        <div id="three">
        <h2 id="pairName">USD/EUR</h2>

          {/* GOAL: show graphs when correct pairs are selected */} 

          {this.displayGraph}

        </div>
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This would be *way* simpler with a look-up table like `{ "USD/EUR": { ... } }`.

Answer (score 4):

In your code I think you are missing `return` before the `<Graph... />`.

However another way you could do this could also be like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    bases: ['EUR', 'AUD', 'CAD', 'JPY', 'NZD'],
    selectedBase: 'USD',
  };

  displayGraph = () => {
    switch(document.getElementById('pairName').innerText) {
    case 'USD/EUR':
        return <Graph defaultBase={"EUR"} />;
    case 'USD/CAD':
        return <Graph defaultBase={"CAD"} />;
    case 'USD/AUD':
        return <Graph defaultBase={"NZD"}/>;
    case 'USD/NZD':
        return <Graph defaultBase={"AUD"}/>;
    case 'USD/JPY':
        return <Graph defaultBase={"JPY"}/>;
  }

  render(){
    return (
        <div id="three">
        <h2 id="pairName">USD/EUR</h2>
          {this.displayGraph}
        </div>
  }
}

export default App;
```

P.s. As a side note, I would look at converting the React class to a function and using the `useState` hook as it is the newer way of writing react code. You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).